# BadCommandLineException with maven cxf XJC plugin

Tags: maven, jaxb, cxf

I'm working on a SOA project using CXF to generate SOAP clients.
I need to use the `cxf-xjc-boolean` plugin to work with Dozer mappings and Boolean attributes, so I followed the docs at http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html and now I have the following `pom.xml` excerpt:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    ...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                        <defaultOptions>
                            <frontEnd>jaxws21</frontEnd>
                        </defaultOptions>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/My.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/My.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-xjc-Xboolean</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
            ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-xjc-boolean</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

When I run the generate-sources goal (either through m2e Eclipse plugin or comman dline) I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.7.3:wsdl2java (generate-sources) on project My-BL: Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.7.3:wsdl2java failed: XJC reported 'BadCommandLineException' for -xjc argument:-extension -Xts -target 2.1
```

How can I fix my pom.xml to have the plunig working?

BTW I noticed that the version 2.7.3 of the plugin (the one, managed, coherent with the version of CXF that I'm using) is not available in the repositories, so I'm using 2.7.0. May this be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Two things are needed:

1. Put the cxf-xjc-boolean dependency in the `<dependencies>` for the plugin, rather than in your project dependencies.
2. The correct argument is `bg` (to generate getXYZ() methods) or `bgi` (to generate getXYZ() and isXYZ() methods) and not `boolean`.

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
       <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>${cxf.version}</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>generate-sources</id>
               <phase>generate-sources</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
               </goals>
           </execution>
       </executions>
       <configuration>
           <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated-sources</sourceRoot>
           <wsdlOptions>
               <wsdlOption>
                   <wsdl>
                       ${basedir}/src/main/resources/PatientService.wsdl
                   </wsdl>
                   <wsdlLocation>classpath:PatientService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                   <extraargs>
                       <extraarg>-xjc-Xbgi</extraarg>
                   </extraargs>
               </wsdlOption>
           </wsdlOptions>
       </configuration>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>cxf-xjc-boolean</artifactId>
               <version>2.7.0</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   </plugin>
   ```